# xdotool redhat 7 creating xdo instance error

Tags: linux, rhel, xdotool

I have installed xdotool package on my redhat el 7 GUI version. installed all the dependencies and it works fine and returns the output. SS for ref.

[image: xdotool in RHEL7 GUI]

[image: RHEL 7 env]

Everything is fine in this redhat version.
I installed RHEL 7 minimal version (server)

gives me
error: can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance.

I have checked env there is no display or XAuthority variables
SS for ref

[image: xdotool RHEL 7 server version]
[image: RHEL 7 env]

checked lot of SO solutions didn't work. been trying to solve it from weeks. Any help is appreciated.

Ready to explore any alternative package as well.

Main idea is to simulate keyword strokes, to perform certain actions.

TIA.

Comment: Allow root to connect. `xhost`.

Comment: tried xhost si:localuser:root but didn't work. says xhost command not found.

Comment: Install `xhost`. Then `xhost +`.

Comment: ok. Did that, now the issue is xhost: unable to open display ""

Comment: Run it from the user that runs the X server. Make sure `DISPLAY` environment variable is set and the user has access to authority.

Comment: i'm running this xhost on linux server version. It does not have any display or XAuthority in it's env list.